# Why isn't my for (key in list) not working like I think it would?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing one of CodeSchool's exercises and I wanted to use the "for in" loop but they use a normal for loop and I'm not seeing why it needs to be that way

```
var canyonCows = [
  {name: "Bessie", type: "cow", hadCalf: "Burt"},
  {name: "Bertha", type: "cow", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Donald", type: "bull", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Esther", type: "calf", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Burt", type: "calf", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Sarah", type: "cow", hadCalf: "Esther"},
  {name: "Samson", type: "bull", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Delilah", type: "cow", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Shanaynay", type: "cow", hadCalf: null}
];

Object.prototype.noCalvesYet = function(){
//return true for an object if the object is a cow
  if(this.hadCalf == null && this.type =='cow') return true;
  else return false;
};

Array.prototype.countForBreeding = function(){
  //this block doesn't work
  var count = 0;
  for(c in this)
  {
    if(c.noCalvesYet()) ++count;
  }
  return count;

  //this block does work (when i comment out the above block, naturally)
  // var count = 0;
  // for(var i = 0; i < this.length;++i)
  // {
  //   if(this[i].noCalvesYet())count++;
  // }
  // return count;
};

//find how many cows haven't had a calf yet and use those for breeding
alert(canyonCows.countForBreeding());
```

Comment: Putting those functions on built-in prototype objects would be a seriously questionable design choice in real production code, if that's not apparent.

Comment: Yah. Thanks =) I've read it's not a good idea, but they're just teaching the basics of how it works. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript `for ... in` loops loop through the property **names**, not the property **values**.

Your array is an actual numerically-indexed array anyway, so you shouldn't be using `for ... in` in the first place:

```
for (var c = 0; c < this.length; ++c) {
  var cow = this[c];
  if (cow.noCalvesYet()) count++;
}
```

Or:

```
this.forEach(function(cow) {
  if (cow.noCalvesYet()) count++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the accepted answer :

```js
Object.prototype.noCalvesYet = function () {
  if(this.type == "cow" && this.hadCalf == null){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
Array.prototype.countForBreeding = function(){
  var numToBreed = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i<this.length; i++){
    if(this[i].noCalvesYet()){
      numToBreed++;
    }
  }
  return numToBreed;
};
```